# Export excel multiple rows with phpExcel

Tags: phpexcel

I am doing export using `phpExcel`. I have `150000 rows`. My export timed out. Is there a way to export excel really fast? `150000 rows` under 1 minute no, Please help me, thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Library phpExcel real delay ! i use [box/spout](https://opensource.box.com/spout/docs/) it runs very fast. My work is very good. But it has some limitations like :

**Not yet support function set auto cell height width increase/decrease?**

***Set style column is manual***

But really its speed surprised me ! I export `120.000 rows` only took 17 seconds.